# Difference between mvn -U clean compile and mvn clean compile

Tags: maven

I used both the commands to resolve dependency issues in my project. `mvn -U clean compile` resolved issues. But I don't know difference between them. Please explain difference between those commands and when do I Use `mvn clean compile` and `mvn -U clean compile`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

-U, --update-snapshots
Forces a check for updated releases and snapshots on remote repositories

[see here](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/running-sect-options.html) (6.1.11. Downloading and Verifying Dependencies):

> -clean will clean (remove all compiled and copied resources) of your maven project target directory.
>
> -install will do almost a full maven lifecycle like testing, compiling AND copying the new builds to your local repository.

-U you will tell maven to update your local repository's remote dependencies (usually third party dependencies) **as well**

Answer (score 4):

```
-U,--update-snapshots                  Forces a check for updated
                                       releases and snapshots on remote
                                       repositories
```

For your information,if you execute **mvn -h** command in the command prompt then it will display all the options just like below. So if you need to know about any option details, you can use **mvn -h** command.

```
usage: mvn [options] [<goal(s)>] [<phase(s)>]
Options:
 -am,--also-make                        If project list is specified, also
                                        build projects required by the
                                        list
 -amd,--also-make-dependents            If project list is specified, also
                                        build projects that depend on
                                        projects on the list
 -B,--batch-mode                        Run in non-interactive (batch)
                                        mode
 -C,--strict-checksums                  Fail the build if checksums don't
                                        match
 -c,--lax-checksums                     Warn if checksums don't match
 -cpu,--check-plugin-updates            Ineffective, only kept for
                                        backward compatibility
 -D,--define <arg>                      Define a system property
 -e,--errors                            Produce execution error messages
 -emp,--encrypt-master-password <arg>   Encrypt master security password
 -ep,--encrypt-password <arg>           Encrypt server password
 -f,--file <arg>                        Force the use of an alternate POM
                                        file (or directory with pom.xml).
 -fae,--fail-at-end                     Only fail the build afterwards;
                                        allow all non-impacted builds to
                                        continue
 -ff,--fail-fast                        Stop at first failure in
                                        reactorized builds
 -fn,--fail-never                       NEVER fail the build, regardless
                                        of project result
 -gs,--global-settings <arg>            Alternate path for the global
                                        settings file
 -h,--help                              Display help information
 -l,--log-file <arg>                    Log file to where all build output
                                        will go.
 -llr,--legacy-local-repository         Use Maven 2 Legacy Local
                                        Repository behaviour, ie no use of
                                        _maven.repositories. Can also be
                                        activated by using
                                        -Dmaven.legacyLocalRepo=true
 -N,--non-recursive                     Do not recurse into sub-projects
 -npr,--no-plugin-registry              Ineffective, only kept for
                                        backward compatibility
 -npu,--no-plugin-updates               Ineffective, only kept for
                                        backward compatibility
 -nsu,--no-snapshot-updates             Suppress SNAPSHOT updates
 -o,--offline                           Work offline
 -P,--activate-profiles <arg>           Comma-delimited list of profiles
                                        to activate
 -pl,--projects <arg>                   Comma-delimited list of specified
                                        reactor projects to build instead
                                        of all projects. A project can be
                                        specified by [groupId]:artifactId
                                        or by its relative path.
 -q,--quiet                             Quiet output - only show errors
 -rf,--resume-from <arg>                Resume reactor from specified
                                        project
 -s,--settings <arg>                    Alternate path for the user
                                        settings file
 -T,--threads <arg>                     Thread count, for instance 2.0C
                                        where C is core multiplied
 -t,--toolchains <arg>                  Alternate path for the user
                                        toolchains file
 -U,--update-snapshots                  Forces a check for updated
                                        releases and snapshots on remote
                                        repositories
 -up,--update-plugins                   Ineffective, only kept for
                                        backward compatibility
 -V,--show-version                      Display version information
                                        WITHOUT stopping build
 -v,--version                           Display version information
 -X,--debug                             Produce execution debug output
```